# How to show the name of the currently executed test method

Tags: junit

I have a larger number of tests and want (triggered via maven) see on stdout/stderr, which test method is currently executed.

I do not want or need that inside the test itself, but rather follow what is going on -- a little bit like IntelliJ does that with the circles that then turn red or green.

Is there a command line option to do this, or do I have to write my own test runner, which does that for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best option is probably a [RunListener](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.java), which you can plug into Maven:

`RunListener` listens to test events, such as test start, test end, test failure, test success etc.

```
public class RunListener {
    public void testRunStarted(Description description) throws Exception {}
    public void testRunFinished(Result result) throws Exception {}
    public void testStarted(Description description) throws Exception {}
    public void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {}
    public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws Exception {}
    public void testAssumptionFailure(Failure failure) {}
    public void testIgnored(Description description) throws Exception {}
}
```

Then, in surefire, you can specify a custom listener, using:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.10</version>
  <configuration>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>listener</name>
        <value>com.mycompany.MyResultListener,com.mycompany.MyResultListener2</value>
      </property>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is from [Maven Surefire Plugin, Using JUnit, Using custom listeners and reporters](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html)

Answer (score 3):

What Matthew wrote works for JUnit and TestNG has a similar interface also.

I'm using **TestNG**, and setting the verbosity high does the job for me:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>surefire.testng.verbose</name>
                        <value>10</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It is documented here http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

> The verbosity level is between 0 and 10 where 10 is the most detailed.
>   You can specify -1 and this will put TestNG in debug mode (no longer
>   slicing off stack traces and all). The default level is 0.

It has also been answered here [Set TestNG's verbosity level from Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099212/set-testngs-verbosity-level-from-maven)

The output then contains such lines as the tests progress:

> [TestNG] INVOKING: "Surefire test" -
>   org.example.MyTest.myMethod(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String)(value(s) ...

Also the @BeforeClass and @AfterClass methods are mentioned.